# JQuery .text() / .html() only working in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a problem.

I want to change an element inside an iframe when an input on the main page changes.

Usually I have no problem doing it, but it won't work on this one and I don't seem to find why.
Here's the code :

```
...
<select name="filiale" class="form-control" id="filiale">
  <option value="14" data-depot="9" data-marge-defaut="" data-cout-assur="0.79" data-mere="1" data-tva="20.0">Actuel Brest</option>
</select>
...
<iframe id="partyat">
...
<span data="soc_nom">PrevVal</span>
...
</iframe>
```

Usually I do something like that (works for 20+ cases ...) :

```
$('#filiale').on('change',function(){
        $("[data='soc_nom']",$("#partyat").contents()).text($(":selected",this).text());
    });
```

But it doesn't work !
So I tried this, but still doesn't work .... I'm lost.

```
$('#filiale').on('change',function(){
        $("[data='soc_nom']",$("#partyat").contents()).each(function(){
            $(this).text('test');
        });
    });
```

Comment: is the iframe on the same domain as the js?

Comment: Make sure you've written the code in `$('iframe').load(function(){}`.

Comment: Yes it is. In fact, I already use my first method on this same iframe over 20 times without any issues ... And my code is already in a `$('iframe').load(function(){}`

Comment: If the `onchange` event firing properly?

Comment: Yep, i tried a console.log() without any issue. I logged the .text() of what I'm changing and it shows the new value in console, but not on the page ...